# Oracle Java stored function - Inconsistent data type for CLOB

Tags: java, oracle, clob, java-stored-procedures

I have a `CLOB` column that stores `html` code. To parse it, I've written a Java stored function -

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION parse_html(value in CLOB) 
  RETURN CLOB  
   AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'MyClass.parse(java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
```

and added a corresponding `Java` class.

When I call this function `parse_html(clob_col_name)` -

```
SELECT PARSE_HTML(m.clob_col_name) 
  FROM my_table m
  where length(m.clob_col_name) > 4000;
```

I got the following error -

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected a value at argument position 1 that is convertible to a Java java.lang.String got an Oracle CLOB
>   00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

### Update 1

As I mentioned earlier, I need to parse the `html` data using `Jsoup`. `jsoup.parse` expects `String` as an argument. Therefore I need to convert `Clob` to `String`. Here is the parse method -

```
public static Clob parse(Clob clob) {
    String value = clobToString(clob);

    if (!isEmpty(value)) {
        return stringToClob(Jsoup.parse(value).text().trim());
    }

    return null;
}
```

This method is doing the conversion from `Clob` to `String` -

```
private static String clobToString(Clob clob) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (clob == null) {
        return null;
    }

    try {
        Reader reader = clob.getCharacterStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);

        String line;

        while (null != (line = br.readLine())) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle this exception
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

And again I need to convert `String` back to `Clob` before returning the parsed value.

```
private static Clob stringToClob(String value) {
    if (isEmpty(value)) {
        return null;
    }

    Clob myClob = null;

    try {
        myClob = new SerialClob(value.toCharArray());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return myClob;
}
```

While calling the function -

```
create or replace FUNCTION parse(value in CLOB) 
   RETURN CLOB  
      AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'HtmlParser.parse(java.sql.Clob) return java.sql.Clob';
```

I got the following error -

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected a return value that is an instance of a user defined Java class convertible to an Oracle type got an object that could not be converted

Since I used `javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialClob` to initialize `Clob`. I don't want to use `Connection` in this case. Is there any way around?

Comment: Erfan, as the message says, you're crreating a function that takes a CLOB as input, while in java you're expecting a string. So, Oracle is NOT converting the string when passing it (as you tell it that you're passing a CLOB), and the java code complains. So either declare (value in varchar2) or in your java class, tell it to expect a clob.

Answer (score 2):

Your declaration of the Java method in *Oracle Java Stored Procedure* using `String` will work only for `VARCHAR2` parameter.

here a simple example

```
create or replace and compile java source named  "HelloVarchar" as
public class HelloVarchar
{
  public static String world(String txt)
  {
    return "Hello " + txt;
  }
};
/

CREATE or replace FUNCTION parse_varchar(value in VARCHAR2) 
  RETURN VARCHAR2  
   AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'HelloVarchar.world(java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
/
```

To use CLOB the option was to declare `oracle.sql.CLOB`, but this class si apparently [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/CLOB.html) compensated with [java.sql.Clob](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Clob.html)

Here a trivial example only passing the parameter back

```
create or replace and compile java source named  "HelloClob" as
import java.sql.Clob;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class HelloClob
{
  public static Clob world(Clob txt) throws SQLException 
  {
    return  txt;
  }
};
/

CREATE or replace FUNCTION parse_clob(value in CLOB) 
  RETURN CLOB  
   AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'HelloClob.world(java.sql.Clob) return java.sql.Clob';
/
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer and the time you spent for it. I've tried this approach too. But had an issue. I've updated my question. Can you please show me some lights on that?

Comment: @ErfanAhmed actually I didn't manage a working example with `Clob` as well. I used for similar case the (now deprecated) class `oracle.sql.CLOB`. My trick was to use a Java *procedure* with two CLOB parameters (input and output) and the *function* was a plain PL/SQL wrapping the procedure and creating a temporary CLOB using `dbms_lob.createtemporary`. You may try it as workaround by compiling the classes with ignore deprecated warning. Good luck!

Comment: May be a case for @KuassiMensah ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use connection, you don't need any additional data to create it.
Here is my solution

```
import java.sql.Clob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class TestClob {
    public static Clob decode(Clob clobParam) throws SQLException {
        String value = clobParam.getSubString(1, (int)(clobParam.length()));
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:");
        Clob cOut = conn.createClob();
        cOut.setString(1, "Decoded " + value);
        return cOut;
    }
}

create or replace function TestClob(obj Clob) return Clob
as language java name 'TestClob.decode(java.sql.Clob) return java.sql.Clob';
```